# How to escape curly brackets in .properties file in Struts 1.2

Tags: java, struts, escaping, struts-1

I have a requirement to retain the curly brackets from properties file in my rendered JSP code. Is it possible?

I have tried options like: `\{`, `'{`, `{{`, `'{'`, `/{`, but no help.

At runtime, I get an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number

The problem is that struts processes the `{}` as a placeholder for a runtime value. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried parsing both the braces like `text '{'some text'}' more text` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it didn't help.

Answer (score 9):

see here http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/how-to-escape-special-chars-in-resource-bundles.html

use `'{'` and `'}'` to escape.

---

Just re-read your question looks like it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I jumped to this problem just 10 minutes ago. This is my try: put '&#123' instead of '{'. (Reference: http://www.asciitable.com/)

Don't use Oct or Hex code since Java will parse these numbers into { before actually reading the key; therefore, it will lead to the same problem. Only HTML code will work, since Java will not parse it, but the JSP page will

Answer (score 0):

From the MessageFormat spec: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

> Within a String, "''" represents a single quote. A QuotedString can
>   contain arbitrary characters except
>   single quotes; the surrounding single
>   quotes are removed. An UnquotedString
>   can contain arbitrary characters
>   except single quotes and left curly
>   brackets. Thus, a string that should
>   result in the formatted message
>   "'{0}'" can be written as "'''{'0}''"
>   or "'''{0}'''".

which means you should probably try to quite your curly braces like this `'''{'`.

Answer (score 0):

Since single quote `'` is always doubled by `struts` before it arrives into `MessageFormat`, you can not produce `'''{'` as suggested by [@Mihai Toader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4625655/1310733). Or any other odd-numbered count of them required by [`MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)

I have ended up using parameters with value `{` and `}`

```
my.property = You have ${0}count{1} unread messages
```

If you supply parameter values `{` and `}`, you get this

```
You have ${count} unread messages
```